# How to unify data in an SQL database?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, sql-update

I have an SQL database with some data like this:

```
code      name
----    --------
1111    Coke        
1515    Pepsi
2222    Fanta
1111    Coca-cola
3576    Dr Pepper
6578    7 Up
2222    Pepsico
```

and I would like the names to be the same if they have the same code. So I expect the outcome to be like this:

```
code      name
----    --------
1111    Coke        
1515    Pepsico
2222    Fanta
1111    Coke
3576    Dr Pepper
6578    7 Up
2222    Pepsico
```

I don't care which of the original names the data finally gets (for example: Coke or Coca-cola, any is fine)

PD: I actually have a much larger database, so I need a general solution, I can't solve this by making update queries for each particular case like this:

```
update tablename
set name = Coke
where code = 1111;
```

Any help would be apreciated. Thank you

Comment: What is your version of SQLite?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
update tablename t
    set name = (select min(t2.name) from tablename t2 where t2.code = t.code)
    where name <> (select min(t2.name) from tablename t2 where t2.code = t.code);
```

This addresses the question that you asked.  However, you have a bad data model.  the `name` should be stored in a separate table, with one row per `code` -- perhaps you even already have such a table.

The name should not be duplicated.  Instead, you should look it up using `JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery to get the first name column for a given code:

```
select t1.code, (select t2.name from test t2 where t1.code = t2.code limit 1) name from test t1;
```

To update your original table:

```
update test
    set name = t4.name 
    from (select t1.code, 
           (select t2.name from test t2 where t1.code = t2.code limit 1) name from test t1
        ) t4
    where test.code = t4.code;
```